# Attaching freestyle styles to a list of collections

Tags: freestyle, collections

I have a simple project with multiple collections. I would like to use three different freestyle styles applied to different collections. Say, I have collections numbered from $1$ through $10$ and freestyle styles $a$, $b$ and $c$. I would like to use the freestyle style $a$ on collections $1, 2, 3$, the style $b$ on collections $4, 5, 6$ and the style $c$ on collections $7, \ldots, 10$. I know that it is simple to restrict a style to a single collection, but this is impractical with a large number of collections (I would have to define the same style many times). Is there any obvious way of matching freestyle styles with collections that I miss?